# In the film version of Goblet of Fire, what are the Death Eaters chanting at the Quidditch World Cup?

Tags: harry-potter, movie, death-eaters

In the film version of *Harry Potter and the Goblet of Fire* a huge melee breaks out at the site of the Quidditch World Cup and a group of Death Eaters march through the campsites, burning them to the ground. There's a tiny bit where we see the Death Eaters walking through the campsites with torches, chanting *something*.

**What are the Death Eaters chanting as they're burning down the campsites at the Quidditch World Cup?**

<sub>I'm a native English speaker and the chanting *truly* doesn't sound like English to me, for what it's worth. Also, I did check the site to see if this question has already been asked and I couldn't find that it has. My Google-Fu skills apparently suck today, meh. I'm pretty sure J.K. Rowling hasn't addressed this; she tends to prefer talking book canon.</sub>

Comment: To me it sounds like they are just chanting the words "Death Eaters" over and over. "Death (step step) Eaters"

Comment: Sorry, pressed enter too soon and then ran out of time to edit: the film script merely says they are chanting "ominous noises"

Comment: @MacCooper - I hear "death", I don't hear "eaters".

Comment: I don't think it matters what we may hear, as its not words in English, according to the script. I think its a coincidence that it sort of sounds like the word death

Comment: Well, no, it doesn't matter in that the world won't implode if we don't get to the bottom of the mystery, but I'm curious and it's an on topic, legitimate question. (I saw *Goblet of Fire* like 50 times yesterday because I was too lazy to change the BD, LOL! Hence my question.)

Comment: Oh no, Slytherincess, that wasn't directed at you! I was saying to Richard that what individuals may or may not hear is irrelevant because the official answer is that they're not speaking in any real language.

Comment: @MacCooper - Oh, no worries! I just wanted to clarify why I was asking. :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This script for the movie [here](http://nldslab.soe.ucsc.edu/charactercreator/film_corpus/film_20100519/all_imsdb_05_19_10/Harry-Potter-and-the-Goblet-of-Fire.html) describes the relevant scene thusly:

> Some figures in pointed hoods carrying flaming torches are walking across the campsite chanting ominous noises.

My guess is that the chanting is not meant to be anything meaningful.

Comment: Except that they certainly sound like they're chanting actual words.

Comment: Thanks very much for the link to the script (I don't know why I wasn't able to find this on my own!). That's interesting that it calls the Death Eaters' chanting just "ominous noises" because, like Richard said, it really does sound like they're saying something in a valid language. :)

Answer (score 15):

I don't know how correct this is, but I'm a Latin student, and the chant really sounds like a derivative of the verb 'interficere' (the specific word they're saying sounds like interfectus) which is the Latin verb meaning - to kill. Many of the spells and potions throughout the series are in Latin, so it really wouldn't suprise me.

Comment: This is a great idea. I, too, am a (former) Latin student, so I could buy that. And you're right -- JKR uses Latin root words for many of her spells and potions; it wouldn't be a stretch for that to carry over to specific Death Eater chants. Thanks for the answer! :)

Comment: Slight correction: it is ***a*** Latin verb meaning ‘kill’. There are many others.

Answer (score 2):

It sounds to me like at 10:54 they say "In death, and then __" (something that I couldn't make out. I'm revisiting this because I'm just watching the movie again and never wondered until now what they were chanting.

Answer (score -1):

Honestly, and this sounds weird, but I heard, "Victor, I love you, Victor I do," like the twins were singing to Ron right before... at least if you listen carefully, it's almost the same tune.

Comment: Welcome to SF:SE. The original poster was ideally looking for something more than just people's opinions on what they (think they) heard

Comment: This seems highly unlikely at best.

Answer (score -1):

I always thought they were saying "mmm, death, death, death, amazing death", like they found the concept of death alluring.